# React this.state misunderstand

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In official example Timer component uses this.interval

```
var Timer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {secondsElapsed: 0};
  },

  interval: null,

  tick: function() {
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<Timer />, mountNode);
```

but why don't use this.state.interval?

Or then why not

```
tick: function(){
   this.secondsElapsed++;
   this.forceUpdate(); 
}
```

If I can use just `this.myPrivateState` why need `this.state.myPrivateState` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to `state` leads to rerendering the component.

You can see that the `interval` is cleared in `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle callback.
Why you would to have interval in `state`, if you need to clear it when the component is going to umnount (going to be removed)?

Put into `state` just things that should trigger rerender of component when it changes.

The `forceUpdate` method is there because sometimes you can know that component should be rendered again, but you are not changing the state, so you must explicitly call the `forceUpdate` method to tell the React it should rerender the component.

Comment: in other words, you can assign properties directly on `this` when they don't affect rendering, but just need to be available to multiple lifecycle hooks or event handlers.

Comment: @cevek: look at this http://jsfiddle.net/xbajauec/5/. This is updated version. It does all the same as your version but using the right React way how to do it. You are basically doing the same, but not the right way.

Comment: @Krab just only "not the right way"? what are the pitfalls?

Comment: @cevek: there are no pitfalls. React is simple. It gives you a way how to maintain component state with getInitialState callback and setState method and later allows you to access the state inside render method as this.state. If you change state via setState, React will render your component again. That's all. You can use forceUpdate and instance properties, because it will have same effect, but why????

Comment: @cevek: what exactly you are not understanding?

Comment: @Krab Because IDE don't intellisense this.state but works perfectly with instance this

Comment: You can use this.something and call {this.something} in your render function if you want.  When you update it you'll just need to call this.forceUpdate() every time.  Which seems pointless because this is exactly what state and this.setState is for and implements in a nicer way with less code.